# can't delete from getContentResolver().delete

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I can't delete a conversation from getContentResolver, I don't know in which part am doing mistakes, as I also searched about these but can't help myself and I also tried different sols which were given on stackoverflow but same result & thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the code:

```
    public static boolean deleteSmsofContact(Context context, String number,
        boolean deleteLocked)
{
    int result;

    if (deleteLocked) {

       //changes values

        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{number};
        String selection= ""+"address=?";

        //
        result = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),selection,selectionArgs);
     // Log.d("UF","WOW "+result+" " +number);
    } else {
        result = context.getContentResolver().delete(Constants.URI_SMS,
                "address=? AND locked=?", new String[] { number, "1" });
    }

    if (result > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is the method from which I am calling:

```
  boolean result = Utils.deleteSmsofContact(InboxActivity.this, sms.getNumber(), true);
                                            if (result) {
                                                dataList.remove(threadPosition);
                                                iAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                Toast.makeText(InboxActivity.this,"Removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }else
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(InboxActivity.this,"cant removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I posted it but did not get the answer so finally I searched a lot on this and the correct answer is until or unless your app is not set a default you can't delete any sms or whole conversation.

Follow [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) it will make your app set a default OR you will be able to delete.